# CakePHP HABTM Association not working

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.4

I've been trying to find an answer to my problem for hours. I am currently working with cakePHP 2.4.

I have two models, Users and Groups. I have created the following associations for each:
(User.php)

> public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
>
> ```
>    'Group' =>
>         array(
>             'className' => 'Group',
>             'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
>             'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
>             'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
>             'unique' => true,
>         )
> );
> ```

and (Group.php):

> public $hasAndBelongsToMany  = array(
>
> ```
>     'GroupUser' =>
>         array(
>             'className' => 'User',
>             'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
>             'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
>             'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
>             'unique' => true,
>         )
> );
> ```

The reason I use GroupUser and not "User" is I get an error because I have already used "User for some other relation.

My form looks like this:

> echo $this->Form->create('Group', array('controller' => 'group','action' => 'add'));
>
> echo $this->Form->input('User.id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $authUser['id']);
>
> echo $this->Form->input('Group.address');
>
> echo $this->Form->end(__('Save', true));

I also have a table called groups_users with "id", "user_id" and "group_id"

When I submit the form, it created the new Group and saves the data, but the association is not created.

I tried manually filling a groups_users record with an existing user_id and group_id but still, when I use find(All), it doesn't find the expected association like it should according to the books.

I debugged the array that is being saved and it looks like this:

```
Array
(
[User] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 39
    )
[Group] => Array
    (
        [address] => asdasd, San Antonio, Texas 78233, EE. UU.
    )



)
```

This is the code in my GroupsController add function:

```
if ($this->Group->save($this->request->data)) {
// redirect or do something
}
```

I have tried changing the array to work with saveAll like in the books, still only created new record but no association. And as I said, I mannually created a record and tried finding it and it wouldn't find it anyway.

Comment: how about `saveAssociated`? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: I think thats for hasMany or hasOne associations only... at least from what I read on the link.  Anyway, I tried it, didn't work.

Plus I think if that were the only problem, I would be able to find the association in my find(All).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it apparently, I think it was because I hadn't created the GroupsUser.php model file. Not rreally sure because I changed a bunch of stuff! But maybe it helps someone.